# Access Denied when doing SQL Backup from another computer

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

**Introduction:**

I'm running my VB.NET program in `local network` with 3 computers, I make daily backup's *with current day name* (so, they get replaced every week).

**Problem:**

When I backup from my `main machine` (which is *server host*), `it backups normally`, but when I try to backup from `another machine`, I get `"Access Denied"` (as shown below) error.

**What I've tried:**

1. Change my default backup folder security options, adding "Everyone" and "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER" all security options;
2. Changed backup string to `... DISK = N'\\192.168.0.2\Backup Sistema\MONDAY.bak'` and also `sharing` that folder and giving permissions to `"MSSQLSERVER"` and `"Everyone"`;
3. Tried to change SQL Server logon in `"Services"` to my main machine username but didn't have success with the password (??) [My computer doesn't have any password];
4. *Spent some hours searching in foruns and trying.*

Note: When I try to make the backup over network (with \192.168.0.2...), It says It couldn't logon into main machine/guest user.

**My connection String:**

```
Data Source=MYCOMPUTER;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User Id=admin;Password=123456
```

**My backup String:**

```
BACKUP DATABASE Sistema_DB TO DISK = 'MONDAY.bak' WITH INIT;
```

**Error Message:**

[image: Error Message]

**Backup Folder Security Tab:**

[image: Permissions]

**Shared Permissions:**

[image: Shared Permissions]

Comment: That `MSSQLSERVER` user looks like a local user, not a domain user; so the remote user (`MSSQLSERVER` presumably) won't have access. You need SQL Server to be running under a domain account that has access to the share.

Comment: I tried to change to my computer domain, but when I try to start SQL service it says "Windows cannot start the SQL Service in a Local Computer Error 1069: Logon failure" (I translated it) @Larnu